# Converting C++ linked stack into smart pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a question on converting the following code into smart pointers, in particular in terms of shared pointers. Node.cpp is an implementation file of the class template `Node<T>`, wherein its constructor is defined as below.

Node.cpp

```
...
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& anItem, std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> nextNodePtr)
    : item(anItem), next(nextNodePtr) { }

...
```

LinkedStack.cpp

```
...
template <typename T>
bool LinkedStack<T>::push(const T& newItem) {

   topPtr = new Node<T>(newItem, topPtr);

   return true;
}
...
```

**LinkedStack.cpp (in terms of shared pointers, my attempt)**

```
...
template <typename T>
bool LinkedStack<T>::push(const T& newItem) {

   std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> topPtr
       = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(Node<T>(newItem, topPtr));
   return true;
}
...
```

Is this a correct way to transform LinkedStack.cpp into the form that uses shared pointers?

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> topPtr` declared a brand new, locally scoped variable and hid the `topPtr` that I assume is a `LinkedStack` member variable. The result is nearly instant destruction of the local `topPtr`. and nothing ever placed in the `LinkedStack::topPtr`

You need to do something more like the pre-transformation version:

```
topPtr = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(Node<T>(newItem, topPtr));
```